# Error implementing anc.clim in the Phyloclim R Package

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am attempting to use the anc.clim function in phyloclim, but am stuck on an error I don't know how to fix.

I have three items in my workspace:
etopo is a 50X14 double matrix with the first column corresponding to 50 bins of an environmental variable. Each subsequent column is labeled with a taxon name.

targetTree is an object of class phylo containing 13 taxa with tip labels corresponding with the taxa in etopo (generated by reading in a .tre file from MrBayes using read.nexus)

prunedPosteriorTrees is an object of class multiphylo containing 1000 phylogenetic trees with 13 taxa with tip labels corresponding with the taxa in etopo (generated by reading in a .t file from MrBayes using read.nexus)

I have confirmed that the taxa in all three match using geiger's treedata function.

When I go to implement anc.clim with these data, the following occurs:

```
> climateReconstruction <- anc.clim(targetTree, posterior = prunedPosteriorTrees, pno = etopo, n = 2)
Error in noi(old, clades, monophyletic = TRUE) : 
  tips are not numbered consecutively. Type '?fixTips' for help.
```

When I type ?fixtips, or ??fixTips for that matter, no documentation is found. I have also searched the web, and the package documentation, to no avail. Has anyone had experience with this error? What do I do?

Comment: You might want to email the maintainer.

Comment: the `r-sig-phylo@r-project.org` mailing list might be useful, too, if no-one here can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem. For the aid of others:

1. targetTree nees to be an ultrametric tree such as one that would result from a BEAST analysis. Mr. Bayes trees are not ultrametric. The same is true for the prunedPosteriorTrees file.
2. fixTips no longer exists. It has been replaced with fixNodes. Using this function solves the error.